# ButterKnife is not binding views and causing exceptions

Tags: java, android, butterknife

I am using Butterknife(10.2.1) to bind views in a project.I recently migrated it to AndroidX.

Though I am doing everything according to documentation here By calling

```
@BindView(R.id.layout_purchase_item1)
View layoutPurchaseItem1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_purchase);
  ButterKnife.bind(this);
  layoutPurchaseItem1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

It is not working and giving me below exceptions:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.sdf.bp.billings.PurchaseActivity.onCreate(PurchaseActivity.java:108)
```

It is clear that the views are not binding here but I did nothing wrong in the layout file as just replacing binding with `findViewById` takes care of the exception. But I want to use Butterknife. Any ideas?

Comment: seems like the view you're setting the OnClickListener is not initialized. And you code snippet is not enough. and the error message is clear enough that at line 108. please confirm the view you setting the OnClickListner is binded.

Comment: Question is updated

Comment: Can you please also add a snippet of your layout file, this could be caused by the wrong id on your layout.

Comment: It is clear that the views are not binding here but I did nothing wrong in the layout file as just replacing binding with findViewById takes care of the exception.

Comment: You could check the code that butterknife generates.

Comment: did you by any chance also start using kotlin in your project?

Comment: @IvoBeckers yes kotlin is used in some modules and in the project also

Answer (score 3):

I have applied `kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'` before. I tried to clean up cache of Android Studio by Invalidate Cache and Restart but it did not work too.
I deleted .gradle and .idea today and after re syncing the project the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please update your build.gradle with below dependencies.

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'
```

After updating inject the view with butterknife.

Comment: I have used this version

Comment: I wrote in the post that I was using that version.

Comment: @JasonBourne did you also add the annoationProcessor line?

Answer (score 1):

Add following lines in gradle file under buildTypes tag

```
   ` lintOptions {
    disable 'RestrictedApi'
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}
```

and in my project gradle file

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```

It is working in my case in same 10.2.1 version with androidX

Answer (score 0):

For the version **butterknife-compiler:10.2.3** the '**kapt**' instead of '**annotationProcessor**' finally helped